# 'struct std::pair<int, int>' has no member named 'push_back'

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct, std-pair

I made a vector of pairs and want to initialize values to those pairs using make pair but I get this error:

> 'struct std::pair<int, int>' has no member named 'push_back'

Here is my code:

```
const int maxm=100005;//10^5
vector<pair<int,int> > v(maxm);

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int x, y;
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        v[i].push_back(make_pair(x,y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because `v[i]` is of type `std::pair<int, int>`, you should:

```
v.push_back(make_pair(x,y));
```

Comment: but i need to consider an array of maxn vectors

Comment: i got to make an array of vectors of pairs

Comment: `v.push_back` adds another pair to your vector at the index `i` - to have `array of maxn vectors` is not clear to me

Comment: i need something like this    (a1 a2 ) (,a2,a3,)(a4,a5 )......say 10 times

Comment: array of vectors would look like: `typedef std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > vec_type; vec_type arr[maxn];`, or better: `typedef std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > vec_type; std::array<vec_type, maxn> arr;`

Comment: @kolaveri - If you want a vector of vectors of pairs then you should declare `v` as such.  Hard to answer a question when it's so obfuscated.

Comment: @kolaveri: "*i need something like this (a1 a2 ) (,a2,a3,)(a4,a5 )......say 10 times*" That is a vector of pairs, which you declared and created. That is *not* an array of vectors, which is what you keep saying you want. So you seem to be confused about the terms "array" and "vector".

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<pair<int,int> > v(maxm);
```

This just makes a single vector of size maxn. What you want is an array of vectors, so you should be doing

```
vector<pair<int,int> > v[maxm];
```